# Capture audio from multiple USB microphones at the same time in Windows

Tags: windows, audio, soundcard

I have Infineon AudioHub Nano, which works as a microphone with 2 microphone sensors if USB-connected to a Windows computer. For my application, I need at least 6 microphone sensors. I am thinking of plugging 3 AudioHub Nano into one computer and writing my software to capture audio signal from the 3 devices at the same time, but I was told by Infineon engineer that Windows only allows my software to capture audio from one microphone at one time.

The reason given is

> A windows or MAC computer allows usage of a single sound-card at any given time. If this sound-card is driving 1, 2, 4, or 8, the operating system does not care. But if there are two sound-cards, it is by default not allowed to use both at the same time. The Audio-hub nano works similar to a sound-card ...

I want to know whether or not it really cannot be done at my software. Otherwise, I need to make a Nano board with 6 microphone sensors.

Comment: A possible way to test would be to run two different audio-recording programs simultaneously and choose a different input device from each one.  If you can get both programs to record audio at the same time, then you can presumably also write a single program that does the same thing.